# Player does not move when Camera follow script is active

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As soon as I add my camera follow script to the camera, my player can no longer be controlled.No error is displayed.As soon as I start the game the x and y position changes to negative during the game.As soon as I delete the follow script everything works again.Can someone help me please?

Here the scripts:
Follow Script:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 

    public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        public GameObject followObject;
     
        public void Update()
        {
     
            if (!followObject)
        {
            followObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        }
 
 
        transform.position = new Vector3(followObject.transform.position.x, followObject.transform.position.y, -10);
    }
 
}
```

PlayerController:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Profiling.Memory.Experimental;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    [Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;
    public static PlayerController PC;
    public float runSpeed = 200;
    public float jumpSpeed;
    private bool isJumping;
private float move;
 
    private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;
 
void Update()
    {
        move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        // Move the character by finding the target velocity
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, rb.velocity.y);
        // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
        rb.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(rb.velocity, targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);
 
        if (move < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
        }else if(move > 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
 
 
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !isJumping)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpSpeed));
            isJumping = true;
 
        }
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
 
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("MGround"))
        {
            this.transform.parent = other.transform;
            isJumping = false;
        }
 
 
    }
 
 
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("MGround"))
        {
            this.transform.parent = null;
            isJumping = true;
        }
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Put it on camera game object

and put player game object to player window in the inspector

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;


public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public Transform player;
 


    public void Update()
    {   

    transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x, player.position.y);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You´re scripts are incomplete and I could not reproduce your error. Did you copy/paste the full source?
I cleaned them up anyway and they work perfectly for me.

Here is what I did.

Camera Follow

- No Changes

Player Controller

- Add a Private "RigidBody2D rb" to the script since it was missing but you were
  using it in Update().
- Move Collision Methods out of Update
- Add closing brackets.

Comment: I habe fix it. The problem was the canvas. No idea why